# Discover available HD storage from inside SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, storage, dmv

I have a SQL Server 2012 instance hosted in a VPS. I can't login on VPS's Windows directly. I know that there are multiple instances installed on that VPS.

I have a query that shows me each DB's file name, that file's size, used and unused space. By their file paths, I can see they aren't all on the same partition (IDK why the infrastructure admin created multiple partitions...).

I need to see each partition's size and free space. Is there a way to find that from a query in SQL Server without having to login on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

I use the below to get SQL Server OS drive partition\volume information SQL Server per instance in both GB and MB.

***INFORMATION:*** This is using a SQL system DM (`sys.dm_os_volume_stats`) and `sys.master_files` table with the `CROSS APPLY` to get the volume information from which that instance can see.  It then does mathematic calcutations (e.g. dividing by 1024 a time or two or three or perhaps multiplying by 100, etc. as you see below in the `CAST` statements) to these and lists in both MB and GB as and uses the `NUMERIC` function.

### ***This will get both `TOTAL` and `FREE` space space per disk partition in both GB and MB as well as the percentage of `FREE SPACE` per disk partition using straight `TSQL`.***

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(vs.volume_mount_point) AS Drive_Letter
    ,vs.logical_volume_name AS Drive_Label
    ,CAST((vs.total_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024) AS NUMERIC(18, 1)) AS Total_Size_MB
    ,CAST((vs.available_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024) AS NUMERIC(18, 1)) AS Free_Space_MB
    ,CAST((vs.total_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024 / 1024) AS NUMERIC(18, 1)) AS Total_Size_GB
    ,CAST((vs.available_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024 / 1024) AS NUMERIC(18, 1)) AS Free_Space_GB
    ,CAST((vs.available_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024 / 1024) / (vs.Total_Bytes / 1024.0 / 1024 / 1024) AS NUMERIC(18, 3)) * 100 AS Free_Space_Percentage
FROM sys.master_files f
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.file_id) AS vs
ORDER BY UPPER(vs.volume_mount_point)
```

SQL Server get drive space information, get volume space information, get disk space information, get disk free space, disk space allocation, report disk space, report storage space

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. In one server I got now records, in another I didn't have permission to run it :/

Comment: @Hikari Yes, this sounds like a permissions issue you will need to talk with your DBA about. You need to see the Operating System partition information thru SQL Server since you cannot see it thru the OS otherwise so ask  the DBA to allow you the permission to run the query above for all those objects, or to build a report to send the data to you, etc. This is basic stuff that a database administrator should be able to assist you with getting a solution in some fashion, the query works just fine from what I tested so the issue you describe is a separate issue you'll need to get worked out, etc

Answer (score 0):

I use below query for my servers on SQL 2008R2 and SQL server 2005:

It involves enabling and configuring Enabling Ole Automation Procedures, within the script and later uses xp_fixeddrives to gather the info.

See if below helps.

```
/*******************************************************/
/* Enabling Ole Automation Procedures */
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
/*******************************************************/
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @hr int
DECLARE @fso int
DECLARE @drive char(1)
DECLARE @odrive int
DECLARE @TotalSize varchar(20) DECLARE @MB Numeric ; SET @MB = 1048576
CREATE TABLE #drives (drive char(1) PRIMARY KEY, FreeSpace int NULL,
TotalSize int NULL) INSERT #drives(drive,FreeSpace) EXEC
master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate
'Scripting.FileSystemObject',@fso OUT IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
@fso
DECLARE dcur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT drive from #drives ORDER by drive
OPEN dcur FETCH NEXT FROM dcur INTO @drive
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @fso,'GetDrive', @odrive OUT, @drive
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @fso EXEC @hr =
sp_OAGetProperty
@odrive,'TotalSize', @TotalSize OUT IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo
@odrive UPDATE #drives SET TotalSize=@TotalSize/@MB WHERE
drive=@drive FETCH NEXT FROM dcur INTO @drive
End
Close dcur
DEALLOCATE dcur
EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @fso IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @fso
SELECT @@Servername
SELECT
drive, TotalSize as 'Total(MB)', FreeSpace as 'Free(MB)' FROM #drives
ORDER BY drive 
DROP TABLE #drives 
GO
```

Comment: I would not recommend to use `xp_fixeddrives` - its undocumented and is do not show the volume mount points. Also, `Ole Automation Procedures`, I find not to enable since its a security risk. Why do you want to use undocumented and probably risky method as opposed to DMVs + **cursor** ?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I didn't have permission to run it :/

Answer (score 0):

```
   select @@SERVERNAME
   ,UPPER(dovs.volume_mount_point) AS [drive]
   ,max(CONVERT(BIGINT,dovs.available_bytes/1048576.0)) AS [Free(MB)]
   ,max(CONVERT(BIGINT,dovs.total_bytes/1048576.0)) AS [Total(MB)]
   ,max(CAST(CONVERT(BIGINT,dovs.available_bytes/1048576.0)/(CONVERT(BIGINT,dovs .total_bytes/1048576.0)*1.0)*100 AS INT)) AS [Free(%)]

   FROM sys.master_files as mf
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.FILE_ID) as dovs
   GROUP BY dovs.volume_mount_point
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. It might be even more helpful if you could describe why this works and how it would help - you'll probably attract more up votes that way as well :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. In one server I got now records, in another I didn't have permission to run it :/